# Org-mode source blocks are not fontified same as the corresponding language

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, themes

i am using Zerodark theme and in my org files I noticed that source blocks (emacs-lisp) are not fontified same as when opening an actual lisp file.

I already have this setting:

> (setq  org-src-fontify-natively  t)

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: If we eliminate using the Zerodark theme from the scenario, does your source code block fontify as expected?

Comment: Yes. If I switched say to solarized then it does fontify as expected.

Comment: Does that mean it is a theme issue? Is there a way for me to fix it?

Comment: By the way, C-' while in zerodark also shows correct fontifying. Very weird.

Comment: Perhaps start by examining the faces in the source code block *without* any user-configuration; e.g., ascertaining the names and colors/attributes.  Place the cursor on a character containing the face and type `C-u C-x =`  Then, type `M-x customize-face` and enter the name of the face and see its attributes.  Then, you can look at the Zerodark theme source code and see what changes it makes and whether you like those changes.  If not, then exceptions can be made in the code or changed after the theme is loaded.  Without access to all that info, I would just be guessing.

Comment: lawlist, thanks. Thank helped. I needed to set org-block to inherit from default and that fixed it.